# Rails 3: How to send HTML e-mails using Aws-SES

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I send an HTML e-mail from the console using AWS-SES gem?

Edit:

From the console or code.

Comment: I think you should rename the title to the particular error you are seeing. And also post the code you have now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses

Try using:

```
:html_body => "<html>...</html>"
```

Comment: I am using aws-ses, howevever, I don't know how to send HTML e-mails

Comment: Added an answer actually reading the question :-) Figured it out reading https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses/blob/master/lib/aws/ses/send_email.rb

Comment: AWS::SES::ResponseError: AWS::SES Response Error: InvalidParameterValueIllegal header 'html-body'. When passing:  :html_body => "<html><body><p> Helllooo </p></body></html>"

Comment: @donald Try removing the html and body tags - just with `<p>Hellooo</p>`

Comment: @egarcia, same error. It doesn't recognize the header :html_body